# More than one rest api configured. Could not infer which API to call

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify-cli

I am using Amplify in my iOS app. And we have a backend team for giving us some external APIs. There was this API which gets called and was working fine. We have to had two more endpoints so they have created that endpoints and pushed it to amplify. After taking the pull the API was not working as expected. It is returning "More than one rest api configured. Could not infer which API to call" this error. Please walk me through this.

This is what the amplifyconfiguration.json file in xcode look like

```
"api": {
    "plugins": {
        "awsAPIPlugin": {
            "companies": {
                "endpointType": "REST",
                "endpoint": "https://j7l0jwnq27.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev",
                "region": "us-east-1",
                "authorizationType": "AWS_IAM"
            },
            "projection": {
                "endpointType": "REST",
                "endpoint": "https://z57ijgfs16.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev",
                "region": "us-east-1",
                "authorizationType": "AWS_IAM"
            },
            "tableCalculation": {
                "endpointType": "REST",
                "endpoint": "https://5nt0tfg2a6.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev",
                "region": "us-east-1",
                "authorizationType": "AWS_IAM"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here /getCompanies was working fine until the other two endpoints came. Now when calling the /getCompanies endpoint I am getting "More than one rest api configured. Could not infer which API to call" this error.

This is how I am calling the API

```
let request = RESTRequest(path: "/getCompanies")
Amplify.API.get(request: request)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is *above*? What *call*? What *error*?

Comment: Question edited please check it.

Comment: "We have to had two more endpoints so they have created that endpoints and pushed it to amplify. After taking the pull the API was not working as expected."  Que!?

Comment: "Please walk me through this."  What is 'THIS'?  You are not helping youself by not showing a single line of code.

Comment: I have included the code

Comment: @ElTomato  Can you help me out now?

Comment: Did you solve this ? if yes, how ?

Comment: @Sravan We have solved the issue as our backend team changed all the apis into a single end point.

Comment: Thanks @VishnuPrasannan, This approach worked. My backend team did the same, for different reason, but the problem solved for front end application.

Answer (score 0):

We have run into simmilar issue and have succesfully resolved it.

The erorr you see tells you that Amplify is unable to decide which endpoint url to use as the configuration specifies more than one.

In order to use multiple endpoints you need to explicitly tell which one you want to use. There is a dedicated parameter in `RESTRequest` initializer to do so called `apiName`, eg:

```swift
let request = RESTRequest(apiName: "<api name>", path: "<path>, headers: <headers>)
```

You need to pass the API name as configued in your `amplifyconfiguration.json` file in this initializer when creating `RESTRequest` objects and then the Amplify SDK will be able to make those requests.

In your case it might be:

Requests to "companies" endpoints:

```swift
let request = RESTRequest(apiName: "companies", path: "/getCompanies", headers: ["header1": "value1"])
let result = try await Amplify.API.get(request: request)
// do something with the result
```

Requests to other endpoint can be done in the same way by passing api name, eg:

```swift
let projectionRequest = RESTRequest(apiName: "projection", path: "/getProjection", headers: ["header1": "value1"])

let tableCalculationRequest = RESTRequest(apiName: "tableCalculation", path: "/getTableCalculation", headers: ["header1": "value1"])
```